# Is there a term used by transgender Christians who don't want to transition because of their faith?

Tags: terminology, gender, lgbt, transgender

I know that some gay/same-sex attracted Christians who choose to follow traditional church teaching and pursue celibacy call themselves "[side B](https://slate.com/human-interest/2014/07/celibate-lgbtq-christians-the-mainstream-gay-community-should-be-more-welcoming.html)" or "gay celibate" Christians.

Is there a corresponding term used by transgender Christians who, despite a desire to, believe that Christian teaching means they should not transition but should live as their assigned gender at birth?

Comment: Are you asking about a Christian with a transgender identity who decides not to transition socially or medically, or a Christian with gender dysphoria who still keeps a cisgender identity?

Comment: @curiousdannii- I guess either? Identity really isn't what I'm asking about, mostly the concept of not transitioning despite a desire to, inhibited by faith.

Comment: Related question on English language site https://english.stackexchange.com/q/514280/192360

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gender wiki](https://gender.wikia.org/wiki/Non-Op) uses the term non-op for persons who identify as other than birth assignment gender but do not wish to transition.

> Non-op refers to those who do not wish to have gender confirmation surgery. Some non-op may wish to socially transition and/or take hormones, while others may not wish to transition at all.

There can be a number of reasons why a non-op chooses not to transition at all.

When the reason for resisting a desire to transition is because of deeply held Christian beliefs it would be appropriate to say the person is **non-op for faith based reasons.**

I could find no single word terminology that expresses all of that.